MWG Exercise 17.B.2
Exercise 17.B.2 of MWG asks us to prove the following.
Suppose we have $N$ consumers, each with access to commodity space $X_i=\mathbb{R}_+^L$ and preferences $\succeq_i$ which are continuous, strictly convex, and strongly monotone. Further, suppose initial endowments $\{e^i\}$ satisfy $\sum_ie^i>>0$ (element-wise), then the aggregate excess demand function $z(p)$, defined for $p>>0$ satisfies $$p^n\to p\neq 0 \text{ with }p_{\ell}=0 \text{ for some }\ell \implies \max\{z_1(p_n),\dots,z_L(p^n)\}\to \infty$$

I have seen the following proof of this which assumes preferences are represented by a continuously differentiable utility function $u_i$.
As $\sum_{j=1}^Ne^j_{\ell}>0$ for all $\ell$ and $p\neq 0$, for $n$ large $p^n\neq 0$. Therefore, there is some consumer, indexed as $j\in I$, which for such large $n$, has a strictly positive amount of purchasing power. That is, for large $n$, $\exists \varepsilon_1>0$ such that $$w^j(p)=\sum_{\ell =1}^{\infty}e_{\ell}^jp_{\ell}^n\geq \varepsilon_1>0$$ As $p\neq 0$, there is $k$ such that $p_k > 0$.
If consumer $j$ is not purchasing any good which has strictly positive price, in the limit their expenditure is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{\ell :p_{\ell}=0}x_{\ell}^j(p^n,w^j(p^n))p_{\ell}^n$$ as since by local non-satiation the Marshallian demand must be such that all purchasing power is utilised and $p_{\ell}^n\to 0$ in the above, it must be that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\max_{\ell:p_{\ell}=0}\{x_{\ell}^j(p^n,w^j(p^n))\}=\infty $$ Otherwise, in the limit, total expenditure of consumer $j$ tends to $0$: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{\ell :p_{\ell}=0}x_{\ell}^j(p^n,w^j(p^n))p_{\ell}^n=0$$ Therefore, $$\max\{z_1(p^n),\dots , z_L (p^n)\}\xrightarrow{n\to \infty} \infty$$ as other agents can only sell up to their endowment amount so cannot counteract the $\infty$ demand by consumer $j$.
If consumer $j$ instead does consume some of good $k$ at prices $p$ which has $p_k>0$, then there exists $\varepsilon_2>0$ such that $x_k^j(p^n,w^k(p^n))$ for all $n$ large (because Marshallian demand is continuous). As $p_k>0$, we consider the case for $n$ sufficiently large than $p^n_k>0$. Consider the consumer's optimisation problem of picking between goods $\ell$ and $k$, where $p_k>0$ and $p_{\ell}=0$. Hold the expenditure on all other goods constant to isolate the trade-off between $\ell$ and $k$. Let $E^j_{-\ell,k}$ be the expenditure not used on goods $\ell$ and $k$. The consumer then solves $$\max_{x_{\ell},x_k\geq 0}u^j(x_{\ell},x_k,x^j_{-\ell,k}) \text{  st. } p_k^nx_k+p_{\ell}^n x_{\ell} \leq w^j(p^n)-E^j_{-\ell,k}$$ The associated Lagrangian is $$\mathcal{L}=u^j(x_{\ell},x_k,x^j_{-\ell,k}) -\lambda  (p_k^nx_k+p_{\ell}^n x_{\ell}-w^j(p^n)+E^j_{\ell,k})$$ First order conditions (strict concavity used here) gives that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{\ell}}(x_{\ell},x_k,x^j_{-\ell,k})-\lambda p_{\ell}^n\leq 0$$ and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}}(x_{\ell},x_k,x^j_{-\ell,k})-\lambda p_{k}^n\leq 0$$ Dividing one by the other... $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{\ell}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))/\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))\leq \frac{p_{\ell}^n}{p_k^n}$$ Where we recover the Marshallian demands by setting $x^j_{-\ell,k}$ to be the optimal choices over goods not $\ell$ and $k$. Because $p_k^n\to p_k>0$ and $p_{\ell}^n\to p_{\ell}=0$, this gives us that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{\ell}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))/\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))\leq 0$$ Because utility is increasing, this is also greater than $0$, so $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{\ell}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))/\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))= 0$$
So, either $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))=\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{\ell}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))=0$. Since we assumed utility is strictly increasing, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{\ell}}(\cdot)>0$. Assume, seeking contradiction, that the sequence of Marshallian demands $(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ stay in a compact set $K$ for all $n$. Then, by Weierstrass $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{\ell}}(\cdot)$ achieves it's minimum so $\varepsilon_3>0$ such that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{\ell}}(\cdot)>\varepsilon_3>0$ But then it cannot converge to $0$. We can do exactly the same argument but with a maximum to show that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))$ cannot converge off to infinity. But this contradicts $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{\ell}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))/\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}}(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))= 0$$ So it must be that the sequence $(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ leaves the compact set $K$. Therefore, $(x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n)))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded. Thus, it must be that $x^j(p^n,w^j(p^n))\to \infty$, so that $$\max\{z_1(p^n),\dots , z_L (p^n)\}\xrightarrow{n\to \infty} \infty$$

How can I adjust this argument to not assume a continuously differentiable utility representation?

Here is a simple proof by contradiction: If this were not the case, we could assume by passing to a subsequence that the sequence $(z(p_n))$ converges to some $z$. The continuity of the inner product shows that $p\cdot z^i\leq 0$ and, therefore, $p\cdot x^i\leq p\cdot e^i$ with $x^i=z^i+e^i$ for all $i$. Suppose $x^i$ were not optimal under $p$ for $i$. Then there is some $y\succ x^i$ such that $p\cdot y\le p\cdot e^i>0$. By continuity of preferences, we can assume that $p\cdot y<p\cdot e^i$ and $y\succ x_n^i$ for $n$ large enough. But $p_n\cdot y\leq p_n\cdot e^i$, contradicting the optimality of $x^i_n$ at $p_n$. So $x^i$ is optimal at $p$. But this is impossible if $\succeq_i$ is strictly monotone and some price of $p$ equals zero; there are no optimal bundles in that case.
The argument is standard; see for example Theorem 1.3.6. of "Existence and Optimality of Competitive Equilibria" by Aliprantis, Brown, Burkinshaw.

Perfect! Thank you. It's so simple in retrospect.
